# Implementation of the idea

Tags: php, mysql

```
$q = mysql_query('SELECT `balance` FROM `users` WHERE `unic1` = "'.(int)$_SESSION['ID64'].'"');
echo $q;
```

Displays: Resource id #17п»ї .
How to display the value?

Comment: Have you even looked at the examples in the [manual](http://uk3.php.net/mysql_query)?

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Choose better title first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net//manual/pl/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) for example to get data.

You should also not use mysql_functions any more but mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0):

Try with [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net//manual/pl/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) like this

```
$q = mysql_query('SELECT `balance` FROM `users` WHERE `unic1` = '.(int)$_SESSION['ID64'].'"');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    echo $row["balance"];
}
```

Comment: Sadikhasan, nothing is displayed

Comment: Can you post your code which you have tried my answer?

Comment: I posted answer here which you implemented code post in question.

Comment: I wrote exactly the same code as your.
Sorry for bad English.

Comment: If you can't post your code here then I cant help further.

Comment: echo your query what it prints just paste in phpmyadmin and what you get just tell me

Comment: This - SELECT `balance` FROM `users` WHERE `jsonid` = "'.(int)$_SESSION['ID64'].'" ??

Comment: What is `jsonid` you mentioned in question `unic1` in where clause

Comment: No, still nothing is displayed.

Comment: please echo your proper query and display here so i can help you according to it.

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0003 sec )

Comment: There is no record found that's why display empty string